# Onkeydown javascript math

Tags: javascript, arithmetic-expressions

I'm trying to create a script where the user enters a number in a field and the script returns values like this:

If the value is below 20 then won't multiply by two;
If the value is above 20 then will multiply by two;

In both cases it will always add 30% based on the value that the user set. For example:

If the user set 20 then will shows 46 at total.

The field will always start as 20 when the users come to the page.

I tried to do it like this, but I couldn't make it

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" value="20"

  onkeydown="document.getElementById(\'coins\').value =
    Math.floor(this.value * 2) + \' coins\' + (int)
    getPercentOfNumber($this.value, 30);"

  onkeypress="document.getElementById(\'coins\').value =
    Math.floor(this.value * 4) + \' coins\' + (int)
    getPercentOfNumber($this.value, 30);"

  onkeyup="if(this.value.indexOf(\'.\') + 3 < this.value.length)
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.indexOf(\'.\') + 3);
    document.getElementById(\'coins\').value =
    Math.floor(this.value * 4) + \' coins\' + (int)
    getPercentOfNumber($this.value, 30);"

  onblur="this.value=Math.max(1,this.value);
    document.getElementById(\'coins\').value = Math.floor(this.value * 4) +
    \' coins\'  + (int) getPercentOfNumber($this.value, 30);"

onmaxlength="3">
```

Comment: What if the value is equal to 20?

Comment: @PeterMader if is equal to 20 or above will multiply by two and  add 30% based in 20, totalizing 46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend splitting that code into a separate javascript function that goes in the `<head>`

Also, you don't need to use all key events, `onkeyup` should be enough for your case.

I put together a very quick sample here:
https://jsfiddle.net/89xa1c5p/1/

Edit:
Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to ensure the input is not treated as a string and no string concat takes place in the operations below

Comment: I agree. The JSFiddle has an error, though, for values less than 20 because it concatenates instead of adds: `outputValue = outputValue + (inputValue * 0.3);` needs to read `outputValue = (outputValue * 1) + (inputValue * 0.3);`.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't test all cases since the answer only provides one example output. Can also be solved by interpreting as number value in the same line: `outputValue = +outputValue + (inputValue * 0.3);`

Comment: If the value is below 10 it is returning a float number, how I should change it to a int? I should use parsetInt(outputValue) above ```document.getElementById('output').innerText = outputValue;``` ?

Comment: @vankk yes, that will discard the decimal. If you want to round the value, you should use `Math.round()`

Comment: @Felipe parsetInt(outputValue) is returning with this error 'ReferenceError: parsetInt is not defined'

Comment: @vankk check your spelling, in the error you show there is a 't' after the word 'parse'. The function name is `parseInt`

Comment: @Felipe Now it is showing 'TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null' that in line ```document.getElementById(\'output\').innerText = outputValue;``` https://pastebin.com/gx3KEWG5

Comment: @vankk the pastebin does not appear to be loading. if you're getting a null error you are most likely not selecting the correct element id. Make sure the name of the argument in `getElementById()` is the same as the `id=""` field of your html element

Comment: @Felipe seems that is only working with span tag, how I use I should use in input tag? Tryed ```<input type="text" class="form-control" id="output" readonly="readonly">``` but isn't working, only works with ```<span class="form-control" id="output"></span>```

Comment: That is because the code is setting the  `innerText` attribute of the `span` element. In order for you to change the value for an `input` element, you need to change the `value` property. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp